# Trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 alongside Windows 7

Tags: installation, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 alongside the existing Windows 7 OS. The Ubuntu installation completed successfully, and it asked me to restart my computer. When I restarted, it was just Windows 7 that loaded as usual, but Ubuntu wasn't there. Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: @Aditya Agreed. [That question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) should answer this even though in this case the problem was not triggered by a recent Windows installation. Sometimes when Ubuntu is installed, the GRUB2 boot loader is not successfully installed to the Master Boot Record; repairing GRUB as detailed there fixes that.

Answer (score 0):

Try boot-repair. It's the only solution that looks feasible. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.